# Why is there such a difference in size between the same tomato plant's saplings?

Tags: houseplants, tomatoes, seedlings

I have miniature "balcony" tomatoes which I've planted from seeds last year, and they gave fruit which have been sitting in the fridge slowly drying down and shriveling for about half a year. A few months back I decided to try and plant these shriveled up tomatoes without taking them apart to get to the seeds inside, just to see what would happen. I think all of them sprouted, but there is a noticeable difference in sizes of the new plants. As you would expect, most fruits have produced groups of small saplings, but some have grown into few, but much more massive.

You can barely see the gaps in soil because I used sprouting pods and planted some of them together into one pot. Why is there such a great difference between the saplings? Is it just because the bigger ones had so few other seeds to compete with for nutrients? Because it doesn't look to me like it would be *that* big a deal, but I may be wrong. Could it be because the roots got stuck inside the tomato fruit's skin? Or is it because some fruit have had more time to mature better than others?

[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced these are tomato plants of any description - the tallest one has enough leaves that it should have started producing leaves that look like tomato plants, that is, lobed edges, though its a little unclear what the smaller ones with only 2-4 leaves might be.

Comment: This tiny pot is just under 10cm in diameter, and the saplings are tightly packed in there. Also, I'm not using any fertilizers and might be watering them improperly. And there is currently not enough light and warmth to really let them grow. There have been a few days so far where I have notices significant growth in all pots between morning and the previous day, but the good weather is yet to come.

Comment: Yes, I understand all that, but have any of the seedlings developed leaves like a tomato plant (different from those in the picture)?

Comment: I think so. Here's today's photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOyk6.jpg

Comment: The small ones in the right hand pot look like tomatoes, but the tall one on the right does not - that may be a weed that's got in the mix.

Comment: I confirm what wrote @Bamboo. I think the tall one is some _Polygonum_ (so a classic gender and family or numerous weeds).  If you touch tomato leaves, you smell its odor (and you will see the yellow in your hand). Very characteristic.

Comment: Those look like peppers.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, nutrients or rather chemistry is not affecting the size of these seedlings.  It is genetics.  One thing people need to understand is the process of making seeds where one can actually put seeds in a packet and declare it is 'such and such' and you will grow 'such and such'.

While growing your own plants and allowing them to make seed (tomato) you have absolutely no idea what pollen has fertilized the flowers and no idea what the genetics (nor genotype or phenotype) will produce.  None.  Pollen flies through the air; from neighbors, tomato production greenhouses, from Home Depot Garden Center.  This unknown pollen is half the genetics that made the seed you are now growing.  Seed to be sold is produced under very strict, sterile, sealed and  controlled environments.

The difference is only genetics.  Go ahead and try to separate into tiny containers (no larger than 3" please) using only potting soil.

No harm in seeing what happens; you'll get tomatoes for sure.  Use potting soil, start with tiny pots and transfer to 1 gallon pots and then 5 or 10 gallon pots...all with potting soil.  Add a little balanced fertilizer (not compost or any source of chemicals that you have no idea of the percentage you are adding, it has to be balanced)...start with even numbers; 10-10-10 then when the flowering begins reduce the nitrogen so that the number, the first number is less than the other two numbers; 5-7-6 for instance. That encourages flowers and reproductive growth which means tomatoes!  Too little chemistry or a little too much chemistry (fertilizer) is death for plants.

Comment: I always, always pay good money for NON GMO seed.  Always.

Comment: I'm growing these for purely decorative purposes, and so I'm not concerned about the nutrient proportions. I simply water my plants (peppers, citruses, mint, different berries) and nothing has ever died on me yet. I manually rumbled around the flowers with a small painting brush for pollination. Maybe some insects got to them first, maybe it's biology beyond my depth, but I don't think there was any pollen other than from trees that grow around my apartment building. I'm pretty sure there are no tomatoes planted in the city, and it's not a popular idea to plant them on balconies like I did.

Comment: No big deal.  Honest.  We have no way to know anything about the 'OP' and their background or even expertise.  I just go on as if they know nothing.  Take no offense, please.  Pollen is in the air from miles and miles away.  There is no way to control plants out of doors for what pollen gets them fertilized.  Trust me, we get so many questions from people trying to grow on their balconies, there are zillions of tomatoes in your neighborhood and beyond.  Did you grow only one species of tomato last year?  Just two will make different plants from the parent...not kidding about the pollen tho!

Comment: And if I am reading you comment correctly you are saying you never fertilize?  So where do the plants get the chemicals necessary to manage this process called photosynthesis?  Photosynthesis requires, Nitrogen, Phosphorous and Potassium as well as the dozen or so micro chemicals boron, calcium, zinc, magnesium, manganese, iron...so on.  Fertilizer is not the same as pesticide (which includes herbicides in the term pesticide).  I've been seeing this idea popping up and am quite flummoxed by this notion.  Fertilizer is critical, as critical as light and water to grow plants.  Quite the science!

Comment: And I use the term chemicals not nutrients...same thing essentially.  Humans think nutrients are like food which is the farthest thing from the stuff they call 'nutrients' for plants, that make their own food; for growth of leaves, stems, reproductive growth and root growth.  Without these, plants will limp along until they die.  Too much and they will die quite quickly.  I do know botany and plants need chemicals to live...

Comment: I just bought a few bags of black "flower soil" and been growing small plants like that on my window sills and balcony without fertilizing it. Just watering every few days. So far I'm happy with the results, as I don't want to have a tall tree in every pot. It's just a low-effort hobby.

Comment: And fertilizer does not make plants abnormally taller or bigger.  Fertilizer is necessary for a plant to do what it does.  Without fertilizer in correct amounts your plant will be slowly dying.  In doors, with less light, less fertilizer is indicated.  But make no mistake, fertilizer is as important as light and water for plants.  Especially plants in pots who depend on you for everything they need to be healthy.  Did that soil come with added fertilizer?  Let me know what the label says.  I am assuming because they called it flower soil that there is fertilizer included (lower N than P&K)

Comment: And Bamboo is correct, these do not look like tomato plants at all.  Interesting!  And those babies look very anemic.  Don't worry about trees in pots.  Trust me, fertilizer is critical.  Tell me what that bag of soil lists for additives.

Comment: Your new picture does show tomatoes on the right...need to know your soil additives before anymore suggestions. But that tall thing is a weed and you have to pull that carefully and thin the rest of those tomatoes to only 2.

Comment: This is what it says on the bag: `Primary nutrient content, mg/l, not less than: Nitrogen (NH4 + NO3) 180, Phosphorus (Р2О5) 300, Potassium (К2О) 350, Solt-suspension 5,8-7,0`. Are you sure it's a weed? The leaves look like a really large version of the little tomatoes. At this point I wanna see what this thing grows into out of interest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59969/discussion-between-stormy-and-user1306322).